# setlocale Format MySQL datetime with php

Tags: php, locale, strtotime, date-conversion

For some reason, it shows me incorrect minutes and hour, and month.
It should show "October" and correct minutes and hour.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'et');

$date = strtotime($row['date']);

echo date("d B Y H:i", mktime($date));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `strftime()` instead of `date()`. (`date()` is not locale aware.)

http://php.net/strftime

And the `mktime()` is not needed. `strtotime()` already sets `$date` as a timestamp.

Comment: That gives me an "A non well formed numeric value encountered in" error.

Comment: Value is 2013-10-20 18:02:56, mysql: datetime

Comment: Got it to work: strftime('%d %B %Y at %H:%M:%S', strtotime($row['date']))